# regex test the first letter of word(s) are capital

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to test the string, either it contains the first letter of word are capital letter. but not getting result.

please correct me.

here is my code:

```
const str = "This Is How it";
const patten = /\b(^[A-Z])\w+\b/g;

console.log(patten.test(str));
```

Actually it should give `false` but getting `true`. because last word `it` not start with capital.

Comment: What about just splitting the string by space and just checking if every entry in the array starts with a capital letter?

Comment: Looking for a simple solution from regex. if not will do

Comment: @3gwebtrain, may be `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+` could help? https://regex101.com/r/Acybps/1 is the Demo link.

Comment: Your pattern only checks if _any_ of the words start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to check a line if all the words inside it begin with a capital letter, here is one way to do it:  [regex Fiddle](https://regexr.com/6vefq)

```js
const str = "This Is How it";
const patten = /^(\b[A-Z]\w+\b\s*){1,}$/gm;

console.log(patten.test(str));
```

using `^` inside of `[]` has the meaning: "NOT any of".

the symbol `^` means something else outside of these brackets: it means the beginning of the line.

[image]

Comment: But getting `true` instead of `false` https://plnkr.co/edit/4sqSqOqCFZwTVqih?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: You are using `match` I am using `test`. for me is all `words starts with capital`?

Comment: `true` is the expected returned value, since your string contains a word that begins with a capital letter. Why are you expecting a `false` ?

Answer (score 1):

- `.split(' ')` the string at each space.
- Run the array through `.every()`
- In each iteration of `.every()`, `.test()` each word vs. `/\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b/`
- If all words pass then `true` is returned else `false` is.

```js
const title1 = "The Empire Strikes Back";
const title2 = "The Return of the Jedi";

function firstLetterCap(string) {
  const rgx = /\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b/;
  return string.split(' ').every(word => rgx.test(word));
}

console.log(firstLetterCap(title1));
console.log(firstLetterCap(title2));
```